# Roslyn auto- compilation in asp.net 4.6 possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, roslyn

I am just getting my feets wet with the new Roslyn compiler platform and i am not quite sure how its auto-compilation feature work (the save file and refresh your browser). As i understand it, it is the Roslyn compiler service that make it possible to auto-compile code just by saving the file. Is this feature exclusively for asp.net 5 ? if so, how comes? I mean, asp.net 4.6 utilizes the Roslyn compiler as well. 
And a quick bonus question on the subject. Does the "auto-compile" recompile the hole assembly or is it smart enough to just change the altered parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is exclusively for ASP.NET Core as it requires many other building blocks, not only Roslyn.

Yes, ASP.NET 4.6 uses Roslyn, but it only replaces the old compilers and CodeDOM in order to be backward compatible, nothing more.